# ASP.MVC: Error running selected code generator "documentId did not come from visual studio workspace" Parameter id: documentId

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I'm trying to use a code first approach in EF 6.1.3 with visual studio 2015. Everything went well and the project builds, however if I want to add a "New scaffold item" -> "MVC Controller with Views, using EF" it keeps giving me the following error:

```
Error running selected code generator. 
The given documentId did not come from visual studio  workspace"  
Parameter id: documentId
```

If I use any of the other Controller it works fine, but I don't want to type out all the code by myself. I have the following files  Any help will be much appreciated. Cheers!

### ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- MODELS ---------------------------------------------------

Models -> Course.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace ContosoUniversity.Models
{
    public class Course
    {
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
        [Key]
        public int CourseID { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public int Credits { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Enrollment> Enrollments { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Models -> Student.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;


namespace ContosoUniversity.Models
{
    public class Student
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string LastName  { get; set; }
        public string FirstMidName { get; set; }
        public DateTime EnrollmentDate { get; set; }

        public virtual IReadOnlyCollection<Enrollment> Enrollments { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Model -> Enrollment.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace ContosoUniversity.Models
{
    public enum Grade
    {
        A,B,C,D,E,F
    }

    public class Enrollment
    {
        [Key]
        public int EnrollmentID { get; set; }
        public int CourseID { get; set; }
        public int StudentID { get; set; }
        public Grade? Grade { get; set; }

        public virtual  Course Course  { get; set; }
        public virtual Student Student { get; set; }

    }
}
```

DAL -> SchoolContext.cs

```
using ContosoUniversity.Models;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Conventions;

namespace ContosoUniversity.DAL
{
    public class SchoolContext : DbContext
    {
        public SchoolContext() : base("SchoolContext")
        {
        }
        public DbSet<Student> Students { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Enrollment> Enrollments { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Course> Courses { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
        }
    }
}
```

DAL -> SchoolInitializer (insitialize data file)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Data.Entity;
using ContosoUniversity.Models;

namespace ContosoUniversity.DAL
{
    public class SchoolInitializer : System.Data.Entity.DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<SchoolContext>
    {

        protected override void Seed(SchoolContext context)
        {
            var students = new List<Student>
            {
                new Student { FirstMidName="Carson", LastName="Alexander", EnrollmentDate=DateTime.Parse("2005-09-01") },
                new Student { FirstMidName="Meredith", LastName="Alonso", EnrollmentDate=DateTime.Parse("2002-09-01") },
                new Student { FirstMidName="Arturo", LastName="Anand", EnrollmentDate=DateTime.Parse("2003-09-01") },
                new Student { FirstMidName="Gytis", LastName="Barzdukas", EnrollmentDate=DateTime.Parse("2002-09-01") },
                new Student { FirstMidName="Yan", LastName="Li", EnrollmentDate=DateTime.Parse("2002-09-01") },
                new Student { FirstMidName="Peggy", LastName="Justice", EnrollmentDate=DateTime.Parse("2001-09-01") },
                new Student { FirstMidName="Laura", LastName="Norman", EnrollmentDate=DateTime.Parse("2003-09-01") },
                new Student { FirstMidName="Nino", LastName="Olivetto", EnrollmentDate=DateTime.Parse("2005-09-01") }
            };

            students.ForEach(s => context.Students.Add(s));
            context.SaveChanges();

            var courses = new List<Course>
            {
                new Course { CourseID=1050, Title="Chemistry", Credits=3, },
                new Course { CourseID=4022, Title="Micro economics", Credits=3,  },
                new Course { CourseID=4041, Title="Macro economics", Credits=3,  },
                new Course { CourseID=1045, Title="Calculus", Credits=4, },
                new Course { CourseID=3141, Title="Trigonometry", Credits=4, },
                new Course { CourseID=2021, Title="Composition", Credits=3 },
                new Course { CourseID=2042, Title="Literature", Credits=4 }
            };
            courses.ForEach(c => context.Courses.Add(c));
            context.SaveChanges();

            var enrollements = new List<Enrollment>
            {
                new Enrollment { StudentID=1, CourseID=1050, Grade=Grade.A },
                new Enrollment { StudentID=1, CourseID=4022, Grade= Grade.C },
                new Enrollment { StudentID=1, CourseID=4041, Grade= Grade.B },
                new Enrollment { StudentID=2, CourseID=1045, Grade=Grade.B },
                new Enrollment { StudentID=2, CourseID=3141, Grade=Grade.F},
                new Enrollment { StudentID=2, CourseID=2021, Grade=Grade.F },
                new Enrollment { StudentID=3, CourseID=1050 },
                new Enrollment { StudentID=4, CourseID=1050 },
                new Enrollment { StudentID=4, CourseID=4022, Grade= Grade.F },
                new Enrollment { StudentID=5, CourseID=4041, Grade= Grade.C },
                new Enrollment { StudentID=6, CourseID=1045 },
                new Enrollment { StudentID=7, CourseID=3441, Grade=Grade.A },
            };
            enrollements.ForEach(e => context.Enrollments.Add(e));
            context.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
}
```

Web config in the root

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301880
  -->
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>

  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="SchoolContext" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0; Initial Catalog=ContosoUniversity1; Integrated Security=SSPI;"  providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>

  <appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="3.0.0.0" />
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5.2" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.2" />
    <httpModules>
      <add name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking" type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.ApplicationInsightsHttpModule, Microsoft.AI.Web" />
    </httpModules>
  </system.web>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.0.0.0" newVersion="6.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Optimization" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-1.1.0.0" newVersion="1.1.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="WebGrease" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.5.2.14234" newVersion="1.5.2.14234" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-5.2.3.0" newVersion="5.2.3.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
  <system.codedom>
    <compilers>
      <compiler language="c#;cs;csharp" extension=".cs" type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.CSharpCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:6 /nowarn:1659;1699;1701" />
      <compiler language="vb;vbs;visualbasic;vbscript" extension=".vb" type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.VBCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:14 /nowarn:41008 /define:_MYTYPE=\&quot;Web\&quot; /optionInfer+" />
    </compilers>
  </system.codedom>
  <system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
    <modules>
      <remove name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking" />
      <add name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking" type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.ApplicationInsightsHttpModule, Microsoft.AI.Web" preCondition="managedHandler" />
    </modules>
  </system.webServer>


  <entityFramework>
    <contexts>
      <context type="ContosoUniversity.DAL.SchoolContext, ContosoUniversity">
        <databaseInitializer type="ContosoUniversity.DAL.SchoolInitializer, ContosoUniversity"></databaseInitializer>
      </context>

    </contexts>

    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="mssqllocaldb" />
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>


</configuration>
```

Comment: Hi @Rodney, were you able to fix this? I am getting the same error and I have no idea what is the root cause of it.

Answer (score 3):

I've run into this problem today, I just unload/reload (right-click on the project in VisualStudio "Unload Project", then again right click "Reload project") the project in VisualStudio and then Rebuild the project and I was able to create the Controller.